# Getting class name from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to retrieve the class name of the last child element (class last div `new3`) in `.find_class`, but my code gives me class `select3`. How can I fix it?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gBxan/5/

```
<div class="find_class mediumCell">
    <div class="new1 old1">
        <div class="select1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="new2 old2">
        <div class="select2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="new3 old3"><!-- I want to get this div's class name 'new3' -->
        <div class="select3"></div>
    </div>
</div>

var find = $('div.find_class div:last').attr('class');
alert(find);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the child selector (`>`):

```
var find = $('div.find_class > div:last').attr('class');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gBxan/6/
See also: [MDN - CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference#Selectors)

Comment: Note that as per the docs http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/ , `:last` should be split out either through use of `.filter` or `.last`.  From the looks of it performance isn't a big issue in this example, but it's good to keep in mind in general.

Comment: How is it for several `find_class` like this html, see: http://jsfiddle.net/gBxan/8/

Comment: @AliciaCibrian See http://jsfiddle.net/gBxan/9/. In JQuery, the context should be a second argument: `$("div:last", this)`. Create a temporary variable outside the function, and store variables in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.find_class').children(':last').attr('class');
```

Comment: How is it for several `find_class` like this html, see: http://jsfiddle.net/gBxan/8/